# Excel macro with filename doesn't work in Office 2016 64 bit

Tags: excel, vba, filenames

I have Excel file that was made with Office 2016 32 bit and today I got updated to Office 2016 64 bit version. Now my files with working Macros are not working partly. I am getting following message:

*Compile error: Can't find project or library*

```
iFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CV_" & ['Filling form'!F7] & "_" & ['Filling form'!F9] & ".xls"
```

Excel 2016 64 bit doesn't like `['Filling form'!F7]` and `['Filling form'!F9]`

What it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue probably is that you used an [Object Library Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/check-or-add-an-object-library-reference) in VBA 32 bit that needs a 64 bit Object Library Reference now.

- From the Tools menu, choose References to display the References dialog box.

Compare that list in 64 bit to the 32 bit reference list. And check if there is a missing reference.

[image]

**It might be possible that there doesn't exist a 64 bit version of your 32 bit Object Library.**
In this case your project is incompatible with 64 bit Office and it is not possible to convert your project to the 64 bit Office without replacing this part with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 3):

Have to say I've never used that form of referencing in VBA - didn't know you could add the sheet reference as well.

Try:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim iFileName As String

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Filling form")
    iFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CV_" & wrkSht.Range("F7") & "_" & wrkSht.Range("F9") & ".xls"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be that the reference library you used in 32-bit doesn't exist in the 64-bit version. In the VBA window, go to "Tools" -> "References" and check if you are missing any library:

[image]

I think the best way to see if anything is missing is to compare the excel sheet on 32 bit and 64 bit version of Excel.